# Python KafkaConsumer in Docker container does not find broker on localhost

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

My goal is the following:

I want a python script which is running inside a docker container (on my local machine) to connect with a kafka broker that is running on my local machine.

My setup:

I have the following python script in a docker image:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer=KafkaConsumer('my-topic',bootstrap_servers=['172.17.0.1:9092'])
```

where `bootstrap_servers=['172.17.0.1:9092']` comes from the docker0 network interface.

When I try to run the docker container I get the error

```
 kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

Kafka is running properly and listening to port 9092. I followed the [quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) guide from Kafka and tested by publishing messages to a topic.

I am using:

- Python Version 3.6.3
- Kafka version 2.11-1.0.1
- Docker 18.03.0-ce
- Ubuntu 17.10 artful

**UPDATE**

I have no been trying to reach localhost from my container with some basic networking tools. Here is what I found out:

- I can `ping 172.17.0.1` from inside my container (no package loss)
- running `nmap -p 9092 172.17.0.1` on localhost yields the following:

  ```
  Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-06 11:46 CEST
  Nmap scan report for arture-VirtualBox (172.17.0.1)
  Host is up (0.00016s latency).

  PORT     STATE     SERVICE
  9092/tcp open      XmlIpcRegSvc
  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
  ```
- running `nmap -p 9092 172.17.0.1` in the container yields the following:

  ```
  Starting Nmap 6.47 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-06 09:46 UTC
  Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
  Host is up (0.000596s latency).

  PORT     STATE     SERVICE
  9092/tcp filtered  unknown
  MAC Adress: my mac address (Unknown)
  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
  ```

So the problem is that there is some filter preventing my docker container to reach port 9092. I never set any filter whatsoever so I would be glad to get help on setting/unsetting it.

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm which listening address did Kafka bind to?

Comment: @Yuankun Kafka listens to port 9092, see edited question.

Comment: I mean the listening IP address. If it is listening on 127.0.0.1, it will not be connectable from the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yuankun suggested a look at the listeners in kafkas `config/server.properties` solved the problem. I added the following line to the server.properties.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.1:9092
```

Now my kafka server is reachable from inside the docker container with a python script.

Comment: what was the docker command you used to run your container? Did you specify --network bridge in your case?